# Does Marklogic Triple store support SWRL in Ontology?

Tags: sparql, marklogic-9, swrl

I would like to understand that if I load an ontology with SWRL rules in it does Marklogic understand it right away or do we need to activate something to be able to get inferred knowledge (SPARQL) according to the rule?

Comment: https://docs.marklogic.com/9.0/guide/semantics/inferencing Nothing about SWRL.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation about rule and rule sets (https://docs.marklogic.com/9.0/guide/semantics/inferencing#id_46963) it seems they use like a SPARQL CONSTRUCT rules to perform inferencing with rules:

```
    Rules ::= RulePrologue Rule*
Rule ::= 'RULE' RuleName 'CONSTRUCT' ConstructTemplate 'WHERE'? 
    RuleGroupGraphPattern
RuleName ::= String
RuleGroupGraphPattern ::= '{' TriplesBlock? ( ( Filter 
    RuleGroupGraphPattern ) '.'? TriplesBlock? )* '}'
RulePrologue ::= ( BaseDecl | PrefixDecl | RuleImportDecl )*
RuleImportDecl ::= 'IMPORT' RuleImportLocation
RuleImportLocation ::= String
```

Or as they provide as an example:

```
RULE "subClassOf axioms" CONSTRUCT {
  rdfs:subClassOf rdfs:domain rdfs:Class .
  rdfs:subClassOf rdfs:range rdfs:Class .
} {}
```